# How to use function in an Observable Object class to use in SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create an array of locations as an observable object variable so that the view updates anytime there is a change to the array. The data in `pins` is being added/deleted in another view. I have created the observable object class as shown with an identifiable struct:

```
struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let pinTitle: String
    let pinDescription: String
}

class Pins: ObservableObject {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var pins: FetchedResults<Pin>
    @Published var locations: [Location] = []

    func loadPins() -> [Location] {
        for pin in pins {
            locations.append(Location(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pin.pinLatitude, longitude: pin.pinLongitude), pinTitle: pin.pinTitle ?? "error", pinDescription: pin.pinDescription ?? "error"))
        }
        return locations
    }
}
```

Then I call the function `loadPins()` in the `.onAppear {}` modifier to the view as shown below however the array is somehow empty when I print the result (`[]`):

```
struct CurrentView: View {
     @ObservedObject var pinLocations = Pins()

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             // view content
         }.onAppear {
               pinLocations.loadPins()
               print(pinLocations.locations)
     } 
}
```

Ideally, the observable object should stay updated automatically when additions/deletions are made to the observable object array from the other view however I cannot even get it to be initialized. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION:**

The solution to this issue is to abstract out Core Data. The @FetchRequest property wrapper is only meant to be used inside of a View. The code below summarizes the approach. All credit for this solution is given to https://www.donnywals.com/. The link to the blog post is https://www.donnywals.com/fetching-objects-from-core-data-in-a-swiftui-project/. I have included the code for quick reference:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceManager: PersistenceManager
    @StateObject var pinItemStorage: PinItemStorage

    init() {
        let manager = PersistenceManager()
        self.persistenceManager = manager

        let managedObjectContext = manager.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let storage = PinItemStorage(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        self._pinItemStorage = StateObject(wrappedValue: storage)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MotherView(pinItemStorage: pinItemStorage)
        }
    }
}

class PersistenceManager {
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
// name is name of core data data model file
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}

extension Pin {
    static var dueSoonFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Pin> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Pin> = Pin.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []

        return request
    }
}


class PinItemStorage: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var dueSoon: [Pin] = []
    private let dueSoonController: NSFetchedResultsController<Pin>

    init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        dueSoonController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Pin.dueSoonFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        super.init()

        dueSoonController.delegate = self

        do {
            try dueSoonController.performFetch()
            dueSoon = dueSoonController.fetchedObjects ?? []
        } catch {
            print("failed to fetch items!")
        }
    }
}

extension PinItemStorage: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        guard let pins = controller.fetchedObjects as? [Pin]
            else { return }

        dueSoon = pins
    }
}
```

Use in view as:

```
struct MotherView: View {
     @ObservedObject var pinItemStore: PinItemStorage

     var body: some View {
         List {
             Section {
                 ForEach(pinItemStore.dueSoon) { pin in
                     Text(pin.name)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your @FetchRequest hasn't actually executed at the time that `loadPins` is called.  What happens if you change `onAppear` on `.onReceive(pinLocations.$pins)`?

Comment: FetchRequest is meant to be used inside a View, not inside an ObsObject. Personally, though, I think it's an anti-pattern API because now (a) your views directly access your model (b) they interpret the raw storage model (!!) and (c) everything about your app is tied to CoreData. What if you wanted to run Firebase for a cross-platform implementation? You'd have to change everything. Best practice is to abstract the database away and have a service take care of it. If you're starting out and watched the CS193 class to get this pattern, that's one disappointing part of the course.

Comment: Yes I am new to this and I think you are totally right that the fetch request is not executing in the observable object class. Is there a way to fetch the data inside of the view so that it updates automatically? I have been able to get it to work using State but this is not ideal since the user would have to interact with the view to update it. @Ryan

Comment: @qsaluan I like this blogger/engineer’s advice for you. https://www.donnywals.com/fetching-objects-from-core-data-in-a-swiftui-project/

Comment: If it works out for you, come back and answer your own question in vocabulary that would help another learner on the topic.

Comment: Let the View decide on when to fetch the data the view depends on. Move the @FetchRequest to the View, please refer to the sample project for CoreData. Xcode > New Project > Check CoreData box and see the example

Comment: @Ryan I have included the working solution to my issue as shown in the edited post. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Fetching data is seamless now but I am unsure as to how to add/delete data based on this way of creating the persistence manager.

Answer (score 1):

MKPointAnnotations & Pins need to be wrapped after fetching from CoreData like so:

```
import MapKit

extension MKPointAnnotation: ObservableObject{
    public var wrappedTitle: String{
        get{
            self.pinTitle ?? "No Title"
        }
        set{
            self.pinTitle = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var wrappedSubtitle: String{
        get{
            self.pinDescription ?? "No information on this location"
        }
        set{
            self.pinDescription = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

You can also Try adding the following functions to your Location class.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    private let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    
    @Published var status: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation? {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }
    
    @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark? {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }
    
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    private func geocode() {
        guard let location = self.location else { return }
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (places, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.placemark = places?[0]
            } else {
                self.placemark = nil
            }
        })
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.status = status
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = location
        self.geocode()
    }
}

extension CLLocation {
    var latitude: Double {
        return self.coordinate.latitude
    }
    
    var longitude: Double {
        return self.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```